Receiving "RAISE NOTICE" when r2dbc-postgresql calls a PLSQL function
Is there a way, that I can access an info message from a Postgres PLSQL function foo, that was created by RAISE NOTICE 'message', when the function is called with SELECT * from foo() from my Spring Boot Java code via r2dbc-postgresql?
For JDBC, I found one answer, but we are using R2DBC.
RAISE EXCEPTION works also as expected, but I need some "normal info logs" in the calling Java code.
It is not necessary, that there is a method available, sth. like receiving the text via a SLF4J log message would be also sufficient.
